# Is using the same SSO for dev and prod considered safe?

Tags: account-security, sso

My company has one SSO provider that we use for our back office apps.  We're looking at tightening security for our SaaS offering.  We have a fork in the road for implementation - we can either continue using non-SSO (Spring Security) and enforcing prod and dev to have different credentials, or we could use our SSO provider for our company's people.  I don't have the security chops to say which one is more secure.  Though managing everything through SSO would be much easier because it's connected to our company AD.

Comment: One concern would be if you use something like Github.  Your dev credentials could potentially be exposed which would also expose your production credentials.  There might also be testing concerns.   (You might want to do some things in testing that are a little risky for a production authentication provider.)